# How to resolve ajax call 'var' (T_VARIABLE) error?

Tags: php, html, json, ajax, wordpress

here is My code.when I activate below code via wordpress custom plugin,It shows 'var' (T_VAR), error .
error:- Parse error: syntax error, unexpected 'var' (T_VAR),expecting end of file in /var/www/wptbox/wp-content/plugins/...... on line ,var data = "";

help me to resolve it.
I found this similar answer ([PHP parse/syntax errors; and how to solve them](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18050071/php-parse-syntax-errors-and-how-to-solve-them),but) I can't get real answer.

```
var data = "";
$(document).ready(function() {
  getHealthData();
});
/**
 *Gets data from API
 **/
function getHealthData() {
  $.ajax({
    type: "GET",
    dataType: "json",
    url: "https://www.hpb.health.gov.lk/api/get-current-statistical",
    data: {
      action: "get_data"
    },
    success: function(response) {
      //getting value from server
      var value = response.data;

      data = "<h5>local_total_cases :</h5><b>" + value['local_total_cases'] + "</b><br/><h5>local_deaths :</h5><b> " + value['local_deaths'] + "</b><br/><h5> local_new_deaths : </h5><b>" + value['local_new_deaths'] + "</b><br/><h5>local_recovered : </h5> <b>" + value['local_recovered'] + "</b><br/><h5>local_new_cases :</h5> <b>" + value['local_new_cases']+"</b>";
      //putting values in div with id="data"
      $("#data").html(data);
      //adding value separately 
      $("#something").text("local_total_cases :" + value['local_total_cases'])

      }
  });
}
```

Comment: the PHP code is responsible for the issue not the ajax call, you need to put the PHP code here.

Comment: @KamyarMirzavaziri 

I have html code and above code only.
<table border=2>
  <tr>
    <td>
 <div id="data"></div>
    </td>
      </tr>
  <table>

Those are working in Jfiddle correctly (https://jsfiddle.net/tx2m4fyn/)
but another checkers says (https://phpcodechecker.com/
https://jsonlint.com/)
above error,my wordpress site also says..

Comment: @KamyarMirzavaziri  error occurs on ,var data = "";

Comment: _“when I activate below code via wordpress custom plugin”_ - what custom plugin? Do you mean something that can execute arbitrary PHP code? Then it probably expects PHP code _without_ `<?php` at the beginning, will be adding that itself - and that would mean, if you start directly with JS code, you will get syntax errors. Try if _leaving_ the PHP parser first helps - `?> { your JS / HTML code here } <?php`